# suhosin alternative

Tags: php, security, suhosin

are there any alternatives available for suhosin? or any recent tools like it? 
i use eaccelerator and i heard that suhosin can't get along with it.

Comment: This question is better suited for serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to APC; suhosin + APC is fine.  This assumes that switching is trivial (which it is, as far as I can tell).  We use APC as a persistent cache, as well as the opcode caching, so that's also a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Suhosin + APC  works great.  But I also recommend using AppArmor.   In fact AppArmor is better at limiting the impact of vulnerabilities against your system.   Its been installed by default in Ubuntu since 8.x,  and is now a part of the Linux mainline.

Comment: +1 for AppArmor, I was unaware of it.  It looks like there would be no problem running suhosin + apparmor, have you had any experience?  It seems that they're doing quite different things, so using AppArmor wouldn't reduce the benefit of using suhosin.

Comment: @El Yobo  no AppArmor and Suhosin work on different levels.  They are commonly used together,  and they are both used by default on Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 0):

Sektioneins recently updated to include suhosin-ng and snuffleupagus

https://github.com/sektioneins/suhosin-ng/wiki
https://github.com/sektioneins/snuffleupagus

There's also non-module alternatives to scan your code for vulnerabilities:

https://github.com/psecio/parse